# How to keep FacesMessage displayed

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I display messages in my application

However, the messages are shown brifely and I would like to keep them on screen until they are closed manually.

How can i achieve this ?

EDITED:

I invoke the run method where messages are made.
I invoke the component pbAjax which then updates the growl element

I use

```
<p:growl id="growl" />  

<p:commandButton value="Run"  actionListener="#{myBean.run}"    id="btnSubmitCreation" onclick="PF('pbAjax').start();" 

<p:progressBar widgetVar="pbAjax" ajax="true" value="#{progressBean.progress}"  styleClass="animated" >
    <p:ajax event="complete" listener="#{controleBean.onComplete}" update="growl" oncomplete="startButton2.enable()"/>                            
</p:progressBar>
```

Java code:

```
public void run() {
    ...
    ...
    List<String> messages = expResult.getMessages();
    for (String message:messages){
       FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,message,message));  
    }
}
```

Comment: Which component are you using to display the Faces Messages?

Comment: well, I write directly in the bean instance, though I am sure this is not a good method

Comment: I meant how you display the Faces Messages in your view (jsp, xhtml or whatever you use).

Comment: I have edited, I hope it is more clear and that I have answered your question

Comment: add `showDetail="true" sticky="true"` in `p:growl` tag then try again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add sticky="true" in growl tag.

Comment: there was a subtle thing: I had to put "update="growl" in the p:commandButton also, not only in the  <p:ajax event="complete"> Anyway, thanks !